# Есть простенькая олимпиадная задача, логически решение верное, но по факту не проходит

Tags: python, геометрия, олимпиада, логика, округление

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT состоит из двух строк. На каждой строке записана информация об одной окружности – координаты ее центра x и y (целые числа, по модулю не превосходящие 5000) и радиус (целое число 1 ≤ r ≤ 1000).

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите «YES», если окружности имеют хотя бы одну общую точку, и «NO» в противном случае.

Моё решение: я нахожу по формуле d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), затем отсюда вычитаю два радиуса и сравниваю с нулём, если меньше или равно нулю, значит точки пересечения есть, иначе нет, но решение проходит только частично

```
from math import sqrt
s = open("input.txt")
x1, y1, r1 = map(int, s.readline().split())
x2, y2, r2 = map(int, s.readline().split())
if sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) - r1 - r2 <= 0:
    open("output.txt", "w").write("YES")
else:
    open("output.txt", "w").write("NO")
```

В решении от авторов используют немного другой подход:
Для начала определимся с тем, что нам известны радиусы окружностей и они равны r1 и r2. Так же по формуле расстояния между точками мы можем вычислить расстояние между центрами данных окружностей:

r = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )

Заметим так же, что окружности будут пересекаться тогда и только тогда, когда возможен треугольник со сторонами r1, r2 и r. Фигуру, две стороны которой лежат на третьей или одна из сторон имеет нулевую длину так же будем считать треугольником, т.к. окружности могут друг друга касаться(r=r1+r2), либо полностью совпадать (r=0).

Треугольник считается возможным если сумма двух любых его сторон не меньше третьей. Т.е. в нашем случае достаточно проверить, что r1+r2>=r и r+r2>=r1 и r+r1>=r2. При этом желательно использовать вещественные типы данных. Так же можно провести аккуратное сравнение с учетом возможных погрешностей при вычислениях.

Но ведь по факту и моё решение теоретически верно, что не так подскажите...)

Comment: *d - это длина отрезка (на всякий случай)*

Comment: Один из случаев, когда ваше решение не подойдет - если одна окружность находится внутри другой.

Comment: И файлы нужно закрывать. Либо вручную через `close`, либо автоматом, открывая через `with`.

Comment: Ну и раз уж целые, я бы работал без квадратного корня (избавился бы от погрешностей вычислений).

Comment: А что именно не проходит? Неверный результат вычислений или код выдает ошибку?

Comment: Неверный результат

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
s = open("input.txt")
x1, y1, r1 = map(int, s.readline().split())
x2, y2, r2 = map(int, s.readline().split())
if sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) - r1 - r2 <= 0 and r1 - sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) - r2 <= 0 and r2 - sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) - r1 <= 0:
    open("output.txt", "w").write("YES")
else:
    open("output.txt", "w").write("NO")
```

Добавив ещё 2 условия решение прошло все проверки, но я всё равно не понимаю почему так, ведь не обязательно использовать треугольник, предлагаемый в решении, достаточно прямой и двух радиусов, лежащих на этой прямой.

Comment: Вообразите 2 окружности с одним центром, но с разными радиусами. Тогда `d = 0` и по вашей формуле `d-r1-r2<0`, что как бы должно говорить о пересечении.  Но пересечения нет.

Comment: АААА, всё, разобрался, я запутался в определениях, что есть круг, а что есть окружность, благодарю